# How setup a2lix_i18n_doctrine for MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm, a2lix-translation

Connect to my project lib "a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle", and have this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]   
Unable to replace alias "doctrine.odm.document_manager" with 
"a2lix_i18n_doctrine.object_manager".
```

I have config for odm:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
  connections:
    default:
        server: "mongodb://%mongo_host%:%mongo_port%"
        options:
            username: "%mongo_username%"
            password: "%mongo_password%"
  default_database: "%mongo_dbname%"
  document_managers:
    default:
        # auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            BlablaBundle:
                type: annotation
                dir: Document/
                prefix: Blabla\TratataBundle\Document
                alias: RE
            FOSUserBundle: ~
            SonataUserBundle: ~
            SonataAdminBundle: ~
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Document
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Document"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
        filters:
            oneLocale:
                class: A2lix\I18nDoctrineBundle\Doctrine\ORM\Filter\OneLocaleFilter
                enabled: true
```

Docs have not info about configuration for MongoDB. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

a2lix_i18n_doctrine doesn't support MongoDB for now.